# How to download and use libraries I need

Tags: file, directory, libraries, openacc

**Error**

```
./cas_seq.fastasim_1A: error while loading shared libraries: libaccapi.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

**Results**

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffefadf6000)
libaccapi.so => not found
libaccg.so => not found
libaccn.so => not found
libaccg2.so => not found
libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f69fa48a000)
libcudadevice.so => not found
libpgf90rtl.so => not found
libpgf90.so => not found
libpgf90_rpm1.so => not found
libpgf902.so => not found
libpgftnrtl.so => not found
libpgatm.so => not found
libpgkomp.so => not found
libomp.so => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f69fa26b000)
libpgmath.so => not found
libpgc.so => not found
librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f69fa063000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f69f9cc5000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f69f98d4000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f69f96bc000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f69fa68e000)
```

When I run a program which is I-TASSER, I got this error message. And I noticed I don't have the libraries on the server. In this situation, what should I do to solve this problem? (I guess I'd rather download OpenACC?)

Answer (score 1):

Are the shared objects included with the I-TASSER installation?  If so, you may just need to set your LD_LIBRARY_PATH to include the path to this location.

If not, then you may want to contact the authors to see if they can supply them. The NV HPC compilers (formerly PGI) license allows for the redistribution of shard objects included in the "REDIST" directory.

Normally you could download and install the no-cost NV HPC SDK yourself to get the shared objects (See: https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-hpc-sdk-downloads)

However here, it looks like this was built with an older version of the compilers. In particular, the "libkomp.so" library has been replaced by "libnvomp.so".  The latest version, 22.2, wont include libkomp.so.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it sir. I downloaded the program which is nvidia-hpc-sdk what you mentioned. However, I have same errors (couldn't find several libraries). To solve this problem, I guess I should reconfigure the server to take advantage of these libraries. Is there any comments for me in this situation?!

Comment: As I noted, it appears that the binary was built with an older version of the compilers where some of the libraries, in particular the OpenMP runtime, have changed.  This is why I suggested you look to see if the authors of the application already have, or can provide, the compiler runtime libraries (found in the "REDIST" directory) for the compiler version they used.

Comment: Where did you get your binary from?  I just looked at the GPU-I-TASSER package (https://zhanggroup.org/GPU-I-TASSER/) and it appears to get shipped as source.  So I'm assuming you got the binary from someplace else.  In this case, you'll want to compile it yourself (though I just noticed a compiler issue with our latest release when building), or got back to who you got the binary and see where they have the compiler runtime libraries located.

Comment: FYI, it looks like the compiler error only occurs with "-O3", so if you do compile from source, change the Makefile to use "-O2" instead.  I have reported the error to our compiler team as TPR#31410.

Comment: Guys~ download pgi compiler (https://www.pgroup.com/support/release_archive.php)

Comment: Note that the PGI archive is only available to PGI license holders or those who have purchased NVIDIA compiler support.  So if you have access, great, but it's best when redistributing applications to third-parties to include the compiler runtime libraries, found in the "REDIST" directory, as part of the application's package so end-users don't need to download these separately themselves.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know it sir. Then, Can you give me more information which compiler I should download to use 'REDIST' libraries in?

Comment: All PGI/NV HPC compilers ship with a REDIST directory, so you want to use the ones that come with the compiler release that was used to build the binary.  Exactly which one that is here, I don't know, but given the names of the libraries, I'd guess it's a 2019 release.  Though if you rebuild the binary from source, you'll want to ship the compiler runtime libraries from the compiler release you used.